# SD Card video not running in the video view

Tags: android, sd-card, android-videoview

I have a video file saved on an SD Card.  The path to it is saved in my database. While running the video file, I fetch the path from the database.

My video path is:

```
/mnt/sdcard/VideoLog/2013-01-01 11.18.57.mp4
```

and the code is as follows:

```
video_view_player = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview_player);
video_view_player.setVideoPath(filename);

//video_view_player.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
//video_view_player.requestFocus();

video_view_player.start();
```

The filename in the video path is fetched from the database.
I even tried converting the `.mp4` video into `.3gp`, but in vain.

Comment: post an answer and marked as accepted. Include *solved* word in your answer. So that it would be helpful for others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

VideoView vv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vv=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(vv);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("/sdcard/sample_mpeg4.mp4");
    vv.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vv.setVideoURI(video);
    vv.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

> VideoPLayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoPLayer);
>     mediaController = new MediaController(m_context);
>     VideoPLayer.setVideoPath(m_videoUrl);
>     VideoPLayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
>     VideoPLayer.setMediaController(m_mediaController);
>     VideoPLayer.start();
>      mediaController.show();